# Using .NET magic get set are best practices?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

It is okay to use this in code (in the mvc 3 context or any other context) :

```
protected String test { get; set; }
```

Would like to hear why it is and why it is not if you have any of those answers.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if it is okay to use automatically implemented properties? Yes, it is okay.

Comment: check out this thread for best answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/c-public-fields-versus-automatic-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a convenience.

All it does is remove boiler plate code for you, since it really is equivalent to

```
private String _test;
protected String test{
 get{
  return _test;
 }
 set{
  _test = value;
 }
}
```

So, when that's all it is, use magic get set.
When you need to do something more funky, then implement the getsetters.

For example, in MVC, I often want to use Enums for my properties, but it is not supported by CodeFirst. So, I do this:

```
[Column("Type")]
public byte DBType;
public MyCustomEnum Type{
 get{
  return (MyCustomEnum)DBType;
 }
 set{
  DBType = (byte)value;
 }
}
```

And this populates my database as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely okay. It is the same thing as using a full property with manual backing, just that its backing is auto-generated by the compiler. If you need greater control over the implementation of get-set, use the verbose syntax by all means, but if you just need  simple properties (for VM properties in MVC for example) use this syntax, as it makes the code much more readable and direct to the point.