# Why Auto-Property?

Tags: c#, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/c-public-fields-versus-automatic-properties)

```
class Person 
{
    public Person()
    {
        Name = "Default Name";
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

vs.

```
class Person 
{
    public Person()
    {
        Name = "Default Name";
    }

    public string Name;
}
```

What is the advantage of the first?

If using like,
`public string Name { get; private set; }` then I understand it.
And yes- I understand why to use properties in object oriented programming.

(and I know also in run-time there will be an private instance of name - but I cannot see 
the big difference - if you just using it like `public string [variable] { get; set; }`)

Comment: I think simple databinding wants to have get and set.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/properties-vs-public-variables.html

Comment: @manojlds: I don't know if Jeff would still think today (the post is rather old) the same think but I disagree with most parts of his post. Another reading: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I often start a property with empty `{ get; set; }` if I'm going to later code up full getter/setter methods.  It lets me get the outline of my code done quickly, and fill in the details later.

I also vaguely remember some data-binding code that only worked on properties, and not on public members. In that case, empty `{ get; set; }` will expose the property to the data-binding.