# Towers of Hanoi Iterative Solution Issue

Tags: c#, loops, stack, pseudocode

I am having trouble with an iterative solution to the Towers of Hanoi puzzle. As this was a university task, we have been given pseudo-code to follow.

```
Towers(number, src, dest, alt)
begin
    push { number, src, dest, alt }
    while NOT stack.empty
        pop { number, src, dest, alt }
        if number = 1
            print "Move 1 disc from " + src + " to " + dest
        else
            push { number – 1, alt, dest, src }
            push { 1, src, dest, alt }
            push { number – 1, src, alt, dest }
        end-if
    end-while
end
```

This is my attempt in C#:

```
static void TowersIterative(uint number, char src, char dest, char alt)
{
    Stack<Move> _Stack = new Stack<Move>();

    _Stack.Push(new Move(number, src, dest, alt));
    while (_Stack.Count != 0)
    {
        _Stack.Pop();
        if (number == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Move one disc from {0} to {1}", src, dest);
        else
        {
            _Stack.Push(new Move(number - 1, alt, dest, src));
            _Stack.Push(new Move(1, src, dest, alt));
            _Stack.Push(new Move(number - 1, src, alt, dest));
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing much is going on with the move class at the moment.

```
class Move
{
    private char _Src, _Alt, _Dest;
    private uint _Number;

    public Move(uint number, char src, char dest, char alt)
    {
        _Number = number;
        _Src = src;
        _Alt = alt;
        _Dest = dest;
    }
}
```

This is an example of the desired output when `number = 3`, `src = 'L'`, `alt = 'M'`, and `dest = 'R'`:

> Move one disc from L to M 
>   Move one disc from L to R 
>   Move one disc from M to R

At the moment, the while loop in the `TowersIterative` method infinitely loops, and the number variable never equals 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `number` variable is used in two meanings - one is the method parameter name, but the pseudo-code's intent is to use it as the value of the `number` property of the element popped from the stack. This should work:

```
static void TowersIterative(uint number, char src, char dest, char alt)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Move>();

    stack.Push(new Move(number, src, dest, alt));
    while (stack.Count != 0)
    {
        var move = stack.Pop();
        if (move.Number == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Move one disc from {0} to {1}", move.Src, move.Dest);
        else
        {
            stack.Push(new Move(move.Number - 1, move.Alt, move.Dest, move.Src));
            stack.Push(new Move(1, move.Src, move.Dest, move.Alt));
            stack.Push(new Move(move.Number - 1, move.Src, move.Alt, move.Dest));
        }
    }
}
```

And of course add appropriate properties to the `Move` class:

```
class Move
{
    public uint Number { get; private set; }

    public char Src { get; private set; }

    public char Dest { get; private set; }

    public char Alt { get; private set; }

    public Move(uint number, char src, char dest, char alt)
    {
        this.Number = number;
        this.Src = src;
        this.Alt = alt;
        this.Dest = dest;
    }
}
```

I've also renamed the variables, to conform to commonly used conventions. See a [Working Demo](http://ideone.com/8CMSzl).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are ignoring the data popped off the stack and are instead using the arguments as if they had been popped off.  I'd suggest breaking `TowersIterative` into two parts to avoid this danger:

```
class Move
{
    public char Src { get; private set; }
    public char Alt { get; private set; }
    public char Dest { get; private set; }
    public uint Number { get; private set; }

    public Move(uint number, char src, char dest, char alt)
    {
        Number = number;
        Src = src;
        Alt = alt;
        Dest = dest;
    }
}

public static class Hanoi
{
    static void TowersIterative(uint number, char src, char dest, char alt)
    {
        Stack<Move> _Stack = new Stack<Move>();

        _Stack.Push(new Move(number, src, dest, alt));

        TowersIterative(_Stack);
    }

    private static void TowersIterative(Stack<Move> _Stack)
    {
        while (_Stack.Count != 0)
        {
            var move = _Stack.Pop();
            if (move.Number == 1)
                Console.WriteLine("Move one disc from {0} to {1}", move.Src, move.Dest);
            else
            {
//              _Stack.Push(new Move(number - 1, alt, dest, src));
                _Stack.Push(new Move(move.Number - 1, move.Alt, move.Dest, move.Src));

//              _Stack.Push(new Move(1, src, dest, alt));
                _Stack.Push(new Move(1, move.Src, move.Dest, move.Alt));

//              _Stack.Push(new Move(number - 1, src, alt, dest));
                _Stack.Push(new Move(move.Number - 1, move.Src, move.Alt, move.Dest));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I changed your fields in `Move` to public readonly properties, since this is generally considered to be [good programming style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/public-fields-versus-automatic-properties)