# Need help in a grouping using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two classes in my code and a List of Class2. I want to group the list elements by `date` and `ID` using LINQ.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string ID;
    public int y;
    public int z;
}

public class Class2 
{
    public List<Class1> a;
    public int p, q;
    public string s;
    public DateTime date;
}
```

My list is similar to this:

```
List<Class2> object1 = new List<Class2>
{
    new Class2 {p = 5, q = 6, date = DateTime.Now, a = new List<Class1> { new Class1 { ID = "3643746HDJ", y = 0, z = 9 }, new Class1 { ID = "746327846HDJ", y = 0, z = 9 } } },
    new Class2 {p = 5, q = 6, date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), a = new List<Class1> { new Class1 { ID = "3643746HDJ", y = 0, z = 9 }, new Class1 { ID = "746327846HDJ", y = 0, z = 9 } } },
    new Class2 {p = 5, q = 6, date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), a = new List<Class1> { new Class1 { ID = "3643746HDJ", y = 0, z = 9 }, new Class1 { ID = "746327846HDJ", y = 0, z = 9 } } },
    new Class2 {p = 5, q = 6, date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), a = new List<Class1> { new Class1 { ID = "3643746HDJ", y = 0, z = 9 }, new Class1 { ID = "746327846HDJ", y = 0, z = 9 } } },
};
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am a beginner in C# programming and LINQ and I am not sure if this is even possible.

This is what I have tried based on examples I saw on the web but its not correct

```
var newList = from item in object1
              group new
              {
                  item.s,
                  item.a[0].x, //I think its wrong because of this
                  item.a[0].y  //and this
              }
              by new
              {
                  item.date,
                  item.a[0].ID  //and this
              }
              into temp
              select temp;
```

Since I have hardcoded index 0 in the grouping I am missing a lot of elements in my final list. How can I do this for all elements of list `a` in `Class2`?

Expected output is similar to this:

```
Key: {date: 19-09-2017 ID: 3643746HDJ}, Element: {{s: "abc", y = 1, z = 2}, {s: "pqr", y = 2, z = 4}, {s: "abc", y = 1, z = 2}}
Key: {date: 20-09-2017 ID: 3643746HDJ}, Element: {{s: "pop", y = 1, z = 2}, {s: "dfr", y = 2, z = 4}, {s: "abc", y = 1, z = 2}}
Key: {date: 19-09-2017 ID: 746327846HDJ}, Element: {{s: "abc", y = 7, z = 8}, {s: "asar", y = 2, z = 111}, {s: "abc", y = 1, z = 2}}
Key: {date: 20-09-2017 ID: 746327846HDJ}, Element: {{s: "abc", y = 7, z = 8}, {s: "asar", y = 2, z = 111}, {s: "abc", y = 1, z = 2}}
```

Comment: Do your classes actually look like that? Like are you using public fields instead of properties?

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Comment: Which `List` elements? How do you expect to group by `ID` when you have multiple `ID`s in the `List<Class1> a`?

Comment: This isn't really related to your issue, but I highly recommend taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1180870/7662085) thread on why you should use auto properties instead of public fields.

Comment: `item.a[0].p` -  for items in `a` there is no `p` property (or `q`)... do you mean x and y

Comment: @stybl I am using auto properties in my code but I didn't want to post my actual code here so I just created these examples classes which are similar to the actual class.

Comment: @GiladGreen yes I meant x and y. Will edit it now.

Comment: @Anon typically it really _helps_ us when your code is as 1 to 1 as possible.  Omitting things like that could make it _harder_ for us to help.

Comment: @Anon - cool :) thought so. See below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question states:

> Since I have hardcoded index 0 in the grouping I am **missing a lot of elements** in my final list. How can I do this for **all elements of list a in Class2**?

As you want all the items from the nested collections you need to flatten the nested collections before grouping. In query syntax do so using another `from`:

```
var result = from item in object1
             from nested in item.a
             group new { item.s, nested.y, nested.z } by new { item.date, nested.ID } into g
             select g;
```

*As each nested object does not have a `p` and `q` properties but your code shows accessing the nested items I used `y` and `z` instead*

This can also be done using method syntax. To flatten the nested collections use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx). For the [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use the overload where you specify both key and element selector. General idea for that:

```
var result = object1.SelectMany(item => item.a.Select(nested => new {item, nested }))
                    .GroupBy(key => new { key.item.Date, key.nested.Id },
                             val => new { val.item.s, val.nested.x, val.nestd.y });
```

---

*Even though it seems it is only for question purposes only I recommend giving meaningful names for properties and variables and to have a look at:*

- [MSDN Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)
- [Dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards)

Comment: Great! This does exactly what I wanted. Thanks for helping and for these links. I'll start following these conventions from now.