# Return two classes from VB.Net function

Tags: vb.net, class

I am working on some tennis project and I need to return some data from a function. I created two classes:

```
Public Class Player
   Public Name As String
   Public Age As Integer
End Class
```

..and

```
Public Class tennisMatch
    Public Surface As String
    Public matchDate As Date
    Public Player1 As Player
    Public Player2 As Player
End Class
```

I want to have a function that returns an instance of `tennisMatch` so I can use it later, I tried this:

```
Public Function getMatch() As tennisMatch
    Dim Match As New tennisMatch

    Dim Player1 As New Player
    Player1.Name = "Steve"

    Match.Surface = "Clay"

    Return Match
End Function
```

Now, this works:

```
Console.WriteLine(getMatch.Surface)
```

However, this doesn't:

```
Console.WriteLine(getMatch.Player1.Name)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the `tennisMatch` object, and the `Player` object, but you never added the `Player` you created to the created `tennisMatch`.

Try this:

```
Public Function getMatch() As tennisMatch
    Dim Match As New tennisMatch
    Match.Surface = "Clay"

    Dim Player1 As New Player
    Player1.Name = "Steve"
    Match.Player1 = Player1

    Return Match
End Function
```

The fact that you named the `Player` object "Player1" doesn't mean anything, you have to assign a value to the `Player1` field of the `tennisMatch` class. The name of the variable doesn't matter. For example, the following should give you the same result as the previous code:

```
Dim somePlayer As New Player
somePlayer.Name = "Steve"
Match.Player1 = somePlayer
```

Moreover, in most cases, you should use [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-create-a-property) instead of fields for the public members of your classes. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1180860/4934172) for more.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, amazing!

Comment: Sorry for asking such a simple questions but I am self-learning and sometimes I have troubles ;)

Comment: That's totally fine. Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: In VS 2017 unless you need code in the get or set, you can just insert the word Property to get automatic properties. `Public Property Surface As String` This preserves the encapsulation principle of OOP as the compiler will create the get and set and the backer field.

Comment: @Mary That's for sure, but this isn't exclusively allowed in VS2017, it has always been the case _at least since VS2010_.