# Why does get, set help me in c#

Tags: c#

Why I shouldn't just make the variable public?
To me, it seems much simpler to just do:

```
public int i;
```

and then accessing it like a normal variable. What do I get in doing this:

```
public int i {get; set;}
```

or even:

```
public int i;
public int I
{
    get
    {
        return i;
    }
    set
    {
        i = value;
    }
}
```

And I don't mean in cases where you want to only get or only set, I mean in cases when you want to use it as a normal variable.

Thanks

Comment: Research the OOP concept of Encapsulation.

Comment: Also, check this: [Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1180860/4934172).