# Passing data from the UserControl to the Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` inside the main form and the `FlowLayoutPanel` is filled with UserControls (of type `UCProducts`).

My UserControl has a PictureBox and an object (of `Product` Class).

UserControl: (simplified):

```
public partial class UCProducts : UserControl
{
    public Product product;
    public UCProducts(Product product)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SomeList.Count; i++)
{
    uCProducts = new UCProducts(SomeList[i]);
    uCProducts.ptcbProduct.Click += new EventHandler(uCProducts_click);
    flpClothing.Controls.Add(uCProducts);
}
```

When the PictureBox is clicked, I want to access the product object inside the `UCProducts` from the Form. I tried to do it with the new event handler, but I couldn't.

This is how I tried:

```
void uCProducts_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox tempPic = (PictureBox)sender;
}
```

Can `Sender` send UserControl directly? How can I pull the product object in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to access the UserControl via the [`Parent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.parent) property of the PictureBox control. Then, you can access its `product` member as you would normally do:

```
void uCProducts_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox tempPic = (PictureBox)sender;
    UCProducts ucProducts = tempPic.Parent as UCProducts;
    Product theProduct = ucProducts.product;
}
```

You probably should convert `product` [into a property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1180860/8967612) though. Also, try to stick to the [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) [naming conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md).