# How to get acess to variables from other classes in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I´ve two classes.
Thats the first one:

```
namespace Working_Times.Klassen
{
    class calcHours
    {
        //Right here i need the value of startTime from MainPage
    }
}
```

The 2nd one is called MainPage

I´ve already tried in calcHours

```
MainPage mP = new MainPage(); 
mP.startTime = 3; //for example, if startTime was an integer
   //it says: mP.startTime not available in the current context 
              startTime not available in the current context
```

Thanks a lot :)
A lot of people have been answering me, the problem would be the acess.
In my case, i guess, that´s not the problem. I´ve already tried to change every variable to public. Still doesen´t run.
SF

Comment: Nobody ever reads exception messages :( _"mP.startTime not available in the current context "_ means that the field called `startTime` of `mP` object is not available in context of your calling method.

Comment: there must be a field/variable/property in `MainPage` class named as `startTime` and it should be `public`. like this `public int startTime;`

Comment: Make sure the property is Public.

Comment: The question [Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/public-fields-versus-automatic-properties) could have an answer you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

> startTime not available in the current context

The problem is that you have not declare `startTime` property in MainPage class. You need add  `startTime` like the following.

```
public class MainPage : Page
{
    public int StartTime { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
       
    }
}
```

> How to get acess to variables from other classes in UWP

You have many ways to do that, fist is declare a property for the like and access property with an instance like above, other is declare static variable and access with class name.

```
public class MainPage : Page
{    
    public MainPage()
    {
       
    }
    public static int EndTime;

}
```

**Access**

```
 MainPage.EndTime = 4;
```