# How are properties different from public variables in C#?

Tags: c#, class, oop, optimization, properties

I have added a data member instead of property and want to set it inside the class and use it at all the other places its called example from references or from classes. How to do it?

expecting minimal code change and no breakage as the code is already in production.

Comment: To answer the question in your title: [Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1180860/9363973). To answer the question in the body: The same you'd use a property. If you're expecting us to give you *any* code change then we'd actually need to see some of your code