# properties without body

Tags: c#, properties, automatic-properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between encapsulating a private member as a property and defining a property without a private member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267144/whats-the-difference-between-encapsulating-a-private-member-as-a-property-and-d)

In C#, usually when I define a property I declare and implement a single line or more for get and set. e.g.

```
public bool IsThere
{
   get { return _isThere; }
   set { _isThere = value;}
}
```

now what does this mean?

```
public bool IsThere
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are auto-properties. They work the same way as your first example, but allow you to omit the unnecessary source code.

They're best used when there is no longer to your getter/setter methods.

They also allow you to add logic to your getter/setter methods later without breaking any calling code (even though you'll also have to implement the private backing property yourself).

Comment: So there is no difference at all?

Comment: @amitkohan - Behavior-wise, no.

Comment: @amitkohan That is correct; However, the shorter version only works for the newer versions of c#.

Comment: The  difference is that you cannot access the internal backing field of automatic properties.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: You can using reflection ;)

Comment: @m-y: Yes, you can use `Reflection`. But that's a kind of hacking and not the normal way C# works.

Comment: @m-y: Also it's the responsibility of the compiler; if you make assumptions about what the auto-backed field is named, you may be surprised when using a newer version of .NET or compiler (though unlikely)

Answer (score 2):

It's an [Auto-Implemented Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) (automatic property).

The C# compiler will automatically create a private field member for the get/set methods to read/write from.

---

Note that there are limitations to automatic properties (for now). For example, you cannot use modifiers such as `readonly`, though you can still mark it as `private set` it isn't quite the same.

Comment: seems like constructor where compiler creates it for you if we don't declare or implement it. right?

Comment: @amitkohan: Yep. Just another lovely part of the C# compiler.