# Understanding Get and Set Accessors

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to learn the basics of C#. This might sound quite trivial and may be stupid but its a doubt. While going through one of the source codes of an application, I saw a piece of code inside a class

```
private string fname;
public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
       return fname
    }
    set
    {
       fname = value;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what it means. I understand that when we declare a class we access `fname` using an alias `FirstName`. If it's for some security purpose then what?

Comment: Take a look at an article about properties - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Comment: I think it's a little off that iBlue should have a down vote for not knowing this and simply asking...

Comment: @Westie title was not the best, that tends to attract quick downvotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [properties in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559909/properties-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is also equivalent to:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

What this do is define a [`property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). In C# properties provide encapsulation for private [`fields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx).

Comment: As a follow up, this also provides a location to add validation (like prevent first name from being assigned an empty value, make sure it's always lowercase, etc.)

Comment: But how does the compiler know that `FirstName` is tied to `fname`? Thanks.

Comment: what is the difference than having only public string FirstName;

Comment: Also you can specify that the property is read-only to the public by saying only `{ get; }`, and still be able to set it inside the class.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your custom logic on your property. F.e, some validation:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
       return fname;
    }
    set
    {
       if (value.Count(s => Char.IsDigit(s)) > 0)
       {
           throw new Exception("Only letters allowed");
       }
       fname = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You get the point across but lets remind people that you don't need to invoke `ToCharArray` to call `IEnumerable` methods.

Comment: OK...i get dat but how do u implement the above code if its like this public string FirstName { get; set; }

Comment: @iBlue There is not difference with simple property and field. Also you can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374416/why-use-simple-properties-instead-of-fields-in-c

Answer (score 2):

fname is a field and has private visibility but FirstName is a public property therefore it will be visible outside of the class and can contain logic inside get and set methods

Answer (score 0):

It's called Properties ([MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)). The reason for using them is to encapsulate accessing some class field to be able to easily change class behavior in future if needed.

This is also equivalent to so called auto-property, since the property at this moment oftimedoes not add any logic:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

get and set methods are called accessors(getters) and mutators(setters) these methods are used to access and mutate the attributes of an object without allowing the access from outside the class. 
See that access modifier of the variable fname is private which means it can only be accessed by any method inside the class.

and note that the get and set methods should normally be given the public access modifier which enables the method to be accessed from any outside class.