# What is difference between these two type of property definitions?

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter

What is difference between these two type of `property` definitions?

**First**

```
public class Person   
{ 
   public string FirstName { get; set; } 
   public string LastName { get; set; } 
}
```

**Second**

```
public class Person   
{
  private string firstName;
  private string lastName;

  public string FirstName
  {   
        get { return this.firstName; }  
        set { this.firstName = value;}
  }

  public string LastName
  {   
        get { return this.lastName; }  
        set { this.lastName = value;}
  }
}
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559909/properties-in-c-sharp/14559922#14559922

Comment: The first format are automatic properties - the compiler will generate the backing fields for them.

Comment: Absolutely nothing in the end. The difference to you during development is obvious (controlling access to the value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second solution is the same as the first one only that it is more extended.

```
public class Person   
{ 
   public string FirstName { get; set; } 
   public string LastName { get; set; } 
}
```

This is the default way of creating a public value, however if you want anything to be done while setting or getting the value you use the second solution, which is the same as the first one but extended.

For instance if you would want to only have names in lowercase you would use the following code:

```
public class Person   
{
  private string firstName;
  private string lastName;

  public string FirstName
  {   
        get { return this.firstName; }  
        set { this.firstName = value.ToLower();}
  }

  public string LastName
  {   
        get { return this.lastName; }  
        set { this.lastName = value.ToLower();}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you might need to add some additional logic before setting and retreiving the value, in such case the second way that you mentioned will be helpful

like if you want to check the length or assign some session value etc 
`set
            {
                ViewState["SomeStr"] = value;
            }`