# Deserializing a list of values from JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization, properties

I have two classes that make use of [auto properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532038):

```
class B
{
    int a { get; set; }
    int b { get; set; }
    List <A> listofa { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    string c { get; set; }
    string d { get; set; }
}
```

I have deserialized a JSON data source and imported data into the classes. Actually I have 3 class `A` objects in my JSON and one `B`. So how can I get the values of my objects that were created?

I can get the values of class B properties by `testOfB.a` (after the deserialization of course):

```
B testOfB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(testjson);
```

But how can I get the value of `testOfB.listofa`? I am sure I should use a `foreach` loop. (I found some examples in some other posts.) But none of it is working for me. I tried something like this:

```
foreach(object[] in A)
{
    ???
}
```

Am I close? Any help would be really appreciated!!

**EDIT**

Here is the JSON I am deserializing:

```
{
    "a": 12,
    "b": 13,
    "A": [
        {
            "c": "test",
            "d": "test"
        },
        {
            "c": "test2",
            "d": "test2"
        },
        {
            "c": "‌​test3",
            "d": "test3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

1. Your member properties need to be public
2. In your JSON the list property is called `A` but in your class it's call `listofa`.  You either need to decorate your `listofa` property with `[JsonProperty("A")]` or rename `listofa` to `A` so that it matches the JSON).
3. You are deserializing to a `RootObject` class which you haven't defined.
4. Your `foreach` loop isn't right, as @billbo pointed out.

Here is corrected code that works:

```
class B
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("A")]
    public List<A> listOfA { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    public string c { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""a"": 12,
            ""b"": 13,
            ""A"": [
                {
                    ""c"": ""test"",
                    ""d"": ""test""
                },
                {
                    ""c"": ""test2"",
                    ""d"": ""test2""
                },
                {
                    ""c"": ""test3"",
                    ""d"": ""test3""
                }
            ]
        }";

        B testOfB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(json);

        Console.WriteLine("a: " + testOfB.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b: " + testOfB.b);
        foreach (A a in testOfB.listOfA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("c: " + a.c);
            Console.WriteLine("d: " + a.d);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a: 12
b: 13
c: test
d: test
c: test2
d: test2
c: test3
d: test3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach statement doesn't look correct. I would write it like this:

```
foreach(A a in test.listofa)
{
    string c = a.c;
    string d = a.d;
}
```

Comment: I noticed some insufficient info from my side. The json and the deserialization looks like this:                               string json="a":12,"b":13,"A":[{"c":"test"."d":"test"},{"c":"test2"."d":"test2"},{"c":"test3"."d":"test3"}]                  B testOfB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(testjson);