# What is the difference between Private Dim and Private Property?

Tags: vb.net, private-members

What is the difference between these two implementation methods of a private variable?  They seem functionally equivalent to me and the compiler doesn't seem to care.

```
Private myTempDir As String = TempAppDir & "\" & Name
Private Property MyTempDir As String = TempAppDir & "\" & Name
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line includes a `Field`/`Variable` and the second one an `Auto-Implemented Property`, which,  as you can read in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx), is just a "quick version" of the conventional `Property`.

You can see advantages/disadvantages between `Properties` and `Fields` in the corresponding [MSDN definition of Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and in links like [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja.aspx).

Also you have quite a few posts regarding advantages/disadvantages of `Auto-Implemented Properties` as compared to the traditional version:

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304/c-sharp-3-0-auto-properties-useful-or-not)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/public-fields-versus-automatic-properties)
- [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673599/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-auto-implemented-properties-with-the-default-acce)
- [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693428/the-case-against-automatic-properties)

These links are for C# but the ideas are easily transferable to VB.NET.

One of these last links refers to another pretty interesting one (also in C#): [Properties vs. Public Variables](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/properties-vs-public-variables.html).