# C# getters, setters declaration

Tags: c#, syntax, getter, getter-setter

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)
>   [C# 3.0 Auto-Properties - useful or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304/c-3-0-auto-properties-useful-or-not)

Is there a difference between defining properties the following way -

```
// private, with getter & setter
private string fName;
public string Name
{
    get { return this.fName }
    set { this.fName = value }
}

// define as a Property
public string Name { get; set;}
```

As far as I can tell, it only looks like a stylistic preference. Am I missing something?

Comment: Effectively not - and this question has been asked many times before.

Comment: @ChrisF it's definitely a dupe, but I don't think the one you got is quite the right duplicate

Comment: @Daniel - it was the first one I found, and as the system allows for multiple possible duplicates it's not really a problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Differences:

- The second form will only compile with a C# 3 compiler or later
- The second form doesn't let any code (even in the same class) access the field directly, as the real field has an "unspeakable name"

The second version is what's known as an *automatically implemented property* (or "automatic property" for short). They were introduced in C# 3. If you're only writing code which looks like the first version - i.e. there's no logic involved - then automatic properties are great. You can always add logic later by converting it into the first form. All your code will be compatible with that change, in both source and binary compatibility terms.

Be aware that in versions prior to C# 6, automatic properties *don't* allow you to specify default values, and there's no such thing as a genuinely readonly automatic property (i.e. one without a getter). The closest you can come is a public getter with a private setter, e.g.

```cs
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

It's not quite the same, but it's close enough in many situations.

Comment: Or "auto-property" for shorter ;)

Answer (score 2):

The first is a standard property.  You must define a field to store the value in.  The second is an [auto-implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), only availible in C# 3.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the IL.  Use ildasm and compare.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it works out to the same thing in this instance.  The difference comes when you want to apply any rules to the getting/setting, in which case you need to use the private/protected variable and hide it behind a public property.

Answer (score 0):

No. Actually, when you use the shorter version (`public string Name { get; set; }`) the compiler automatically generates a private field for the property.