# C# Getter Setter in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, getter-setter

I made my website with the ViewBag, but from Java I know there are getter and setters for that. I know how I can create this getter and setter but I don't know how I can get the values in my CSHTML-File?
I tried it with:

```
<p>Message1: @Model1.test</p>
<p>Message2: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.test)</p>
```

Thanks for your help

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Model1 model = new Model1();
        model.test = "Hallo Test!";
        return View();
    }
```

Model:

```
public string test { get; set; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getter and Setter declaration in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881091/getter-and-setter-declaration-in-net)

Comment: What does or doesn't this code do? Please read [ask].

Comment: Show your controller method. Where you want to set your variable and where you want to get it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @ShakirAhamed it is not a duplicate

Comment: I want just have a little mvc application where I can set a string in the controller and show it on a view.

Comment: tell view what data to show, you can use dynamic dictionaries like viewbag, tempdata,  or "return view(model);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a ViewModel.And put in View method as below

```
 public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

In your Action Method

```
Model model = new Model();
model.Id = 1;
return View(model);
```

In you view

```
@model ProjectName.Model'sFolderName.Model
```

You can use Model in your view now

Comment: thanks :) I forgot to give the model back in the  return tag