# What does this line with auto-implemented properties with a static class mean?

Tags: c#, static, getter-setter

I'm following the instructions for testing an azure function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#c-in-visual-studio) and I came across this line of code:

```
public static NullScope Instance { get; } = new NullScope();
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881091/getter-and-setter-declaration-in-net) SO answer, so I understand auto-implemented properties, but I don't know how it combines with the `static` keyword.

Is this just creating a new Nullscope that you can only access and not set? Or does this create a new NullScope every time you `get` it? If possible, could you expand the line of code for better understanding?

Comment: thats a readonly property that returns the same reference everytime.

Comment: The first: it creates an instance at the very first access of the class containing the property, and sets its value to the instance. It will be practically  read-only.

Comment: that mostly a Singleton pattern implementation

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvotes and how I could improve upon this question for next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this just creating a new Nullscope that you can only access and not set?

Yes, exactly.

> Or does this create a new NullScope every time you get it?

No, that would look more like this:

```
public static NullScope Instance
{
    get => new NullScope();
}
```

Notice that the former has a standard auto-implemented getter and uses some relatively recent syntax to set a value to the auto-implemented backing member, whereas the latter uses a custom getter which is just an "expression bodied member" which, when invoked, returns an object.