# Cannot print elements from the list

Tags: c#, list

```
public class item
{
  public int x;  
  public string s;
  public item ()
  {}
}
```

Then in the main method, I try to create a list and print out the elements in it.

```
{
  item first=new item();
  first.x=5;
  first.s="Hello";
 
  item second =new item();
  second.x=6;
  second.s="world";

  List <item> myItem= new List <item> ();
  myItem.Add(first);
  myItem.Add(second);
  
  foreach (item element in myItem)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(element);
  }
}
```

There is no syntax error, but terminal returns nothing when I try to run the code above.

Comment: Try to use your objects fields, Console.WriteLine("x: " + element.x.ToString() + " s: " + element.s); This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360277/what-is-the-best-way-to-dump-entire-objects-to-a-log-in-c

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than snippets. I would expect that to print `item` twice, as the default implementation for `ToString()` just returns the class name. (As an aside, I'd strongly suggest learning and following C# naming conventions as early as possible.)

Comment: _"There is no syntax error"_ false. This doesn't compile. `first.x=5;` will not work, as `int x` has no accessor defined, thus is private. And you are using `y`, which is not defined.

Comment: I fixed the typo and adding access modifier to the field variables, so that it will not confuse people, thank you.

Comment: We're still missing a [mcve]. Again, I'd expect that to print `item` twice. If it's not printing anything for you, there may be something else going on... but we can't help you if we can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler will not magically know how to convert your custom type to a string. However, each class derives from the `object` class, that has a (virtual) `ToString` method. If not overwritten, it will print the class name.
You can [override it yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) in the `item` class. E.g.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "x: " + x + ", s: " + s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are following can be improved. See this-
[Getter and Setter declaration in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881091/getter-and-setter-declaration-in-net)

and you have defined variable in class as

```
int x;
string s;
```

and using as

```
first.x=5;
first.y="Hello"; // what is y here? It is not defined in your model class
```

in your approach, list elements can be printed like this (currently properties in your item class are private, you have make them public or see @jhbonarius answer for toString method)

```
foreach (item element in myItem)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(element.x +" "+element.s);
  }
```

Comment: No. If the accessor is not defined, it is private by default. So x and s are not accessible from outside of the class

Comment: yes, thanks @JHBonarius, I have noted that in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek and JHBonarius for pointing out the issues. So is this saying that can only use 'Console.WriteLine (element);' when the items in the lists are the same variable type, i.e. all int or all string?

Answer (score 0):

Please, use PascalCase for definitions of classes and fields.

```
public class Item
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
}
```

The WriteLine method automatically calls the ToString method to 'transform' the object into a string.

If you want to see the values ​​of the fields you have to write:

```
Console.WriteLine(“A: ” + item.A + “ X: “ + item.X);
// or w/ string interpolation
Console.WriteLine($”A: {item.A} X: {item.X}”);

// console output
A: ‘value of A’ X: ‘value of X’
```

You could also override the ToString method within the ‘Item’ class.

```
public class Item
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "A: " + A + " X: " + X;
    }
}
```

And to write the value on console just write

```
Console.WriteLine(item);

// console output
A: ‘value of A’ X: ‘value of X’
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are trying to print the whole item.
You can do that if you implement a ToString() method (like in the answer above by JHBonarius) in your "item" class and then call :

```
foreach (item element in myItem)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.ToString()); .
}
```

Or you try to print the exact propertiest of your "item" like:

```
foreach (item element in myItem)
{
    Console.WriteLine("x: " + element.x.ToString() + " s: " element.s.ToString()); 
}
```

And definitely change your class definition to the one @SteeBono recommends above .

```
public class item
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public string s { get; set; }
}
```

In case you want to print out your properties dynamically you can use iterate through all of the properties of you class ("item" in this case) :

```
foreach (var element in myItem)
{
    elementPrintData += "Element : \n";

    foreach (var fromProp in typeof(item).GetProperties())
    {
        var toProp = typeof(item).GetProperty(fromProp.Name);
        var toValue = toProp.GetValue(element, null);
        string val = "";
        if (toValue != null)
        {
            // this will try to print DateTime if present, might need to add null check
            if (toProp.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?) || toProp.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                val = ((DateTime)toValue).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            else
                val = toValue.ToString();
        }

    // this will print the property name with the value (int, string, bool, double...) 
    //if it is not a collection/list
    // each property will go into a new line because of the " \n"
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) && !val.Contains("System.Collections"))
            elementPrintData += toProp.Name + ": " + val + " \n";
   }
}
```