# What's the difference between two ways of getter and setter. which is better?

Tags: c#

There are two ways to implement the getter and setter.

A:

```
public Object Name {get;set;}
```

B:

```
private Object _name;
public Object Name
{
       get {return this._name;}
       set {this._name = value;}
}
```

When we wanner get or set the property we all use

```
X.Name = "Joy";
String name = X.Name
```

So I just want to know the difference between them.

Thank you.

Comment: [What are Automatic Properties in C# and what is their purpose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001917/what-are-automatic-properties-in-c-sharp-and-what-is-their-purpose)

Comment: Short answer: there is no difference. You use the first when you can and the second when you must.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) which is basically [syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001917/what-are-automatic-properties-in-c-sharp-and-what-is-their-purpose) and results in the same as the second approach.

When using the first auto implemented properties the c# compiler will generate a backing field just like you have it declared in the second case.

If you want to make the property read only you can use declare it like this:

`public Object Name {get; private set;}`

Answer (score 1):

They're just the same. The first one is just syntactic sugar.

But if you want to add some logic, say validate the setter value, the second one is what you need.