# set is throwing StackOverflowException C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get and send a list of this object to a text file. The text file is in the following format.

```
name,IDnumber,department,value
```

there are quite a few lines of this so i used a for to read them in.
This is the code for the read and write to the file.

```
    public List<Employee> ReadFile(string fileName) {
        StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(fileName);
        fileIn = File.OpenText(fileName);
        List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
        string[] test;
        string name;
        string ID;
        string dep;
        string post;

        while (!fileIn.EndOfStream || !File.Exists(fileName)) {

            string inString = fileIn.ReadLine();
            test = inString.Split('#');
            name = test[0];
            ID = test[1];
            dep = test[2];
            post = test[3];
            Employee newEmp = new Employee(name, ID, dep, post);
            list.Add(newEmp);

        }
        fileIn.Close();
        return list;
    }
```

---

```
    public void WriteFile(List<Employee> outList, string file) {

        StreamWriter writeOut = new StreamWriter(file);

        for (int i = 0; i < outList.Count; i++) {

            writeOut.WriteLine(outList[i].name + '#' + outList[i].IDnum + '#' + outList[i].department + '#' + outList[i].position);

        }
        writeOut.close();
    }
```

This is the code for my class. The error is being thrown at the set.

```
public class Employee {

    public string name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    public string IDnum { get { return IDnum; } set { IDnum = value; } }
    public string department { get { return department; } set { department = value; } }
    public string position { get { return position; } set { position = value; } }

    public Employee() {

        name = string.Empty;
        IDnum = string.Empty;
        department = string.Empty;
        position = string.Empty;

    }

    public Employee(string newName, string newID) {

        name = newName;
        IDnum = newID;
        department = string.Empty;
        position = string.Empty;

    }

    public Employee(string newName, string newID, string newDep, string
    newPost) {

        name = newName;
        IDnum = newID;
        department = newPost;
        position = newDep;

    }

}
```

I am not sure if there is some kind of formatting that I am missing for the set function to function as needed. The This is the function i am calling for the in and out of the file. I believe that it is never making it to the out so it is likely how i am importing the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a really common gotcha... a C# rite of passage!

Let's take a look at a single property *(this applies to all of your properties though)*...

```
public string name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
```

so what happens when you try `myObj.name = "foo";`?

In the `set` method, you refer back to the very same property `name`. So it tries to access `name`, which goes around again (and again, and again, recursively until you StackOverflow).

A backing field with proper naming conventions is the norm here:

```
private string name;
public string Name{get { return name; } set{ name = value; }}
```

or even better, if there's no logic involved, an [auto-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001917/what-are-automatic-properties-in-c-sharp-and-what-is-their-purpose).

```
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You keep calling IDnum *and other properties* over and over recursively, until the stack overflows

```
public string IDnum { get { return IDnum; } set { IDnum = value; } }
```

When you do something like

```
IDnum = someValue;
```

that calls the setter for `IDnum`, which runs the code in the setter

IDnum = value

Which in turn calls the setter of IDnum, until you run out of stack.

**The Fix**

In your case, it looks like you can use automatic properties

```
public string IDnum { get; set; }
```

Comment: So, how should the syntax be? should it just be
`get {return IDnum;` and 
`set{ IDnum = value;`

Comment: ++, and the other properties have the same problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was having trouble with the automatic before but looks like i corrected my error causing that.

Comment: Glad you worked it out.  If you did not want to use automatic properties, you would have to setup a variable to store the property value (called the "backing store", using a different name e.g. `private string idnum;`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
public string name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
public string IDnum { get { return IDnum; } set { IDnum = value; } }
public string department { get { return department; } set { department = value; } }
public string position { get { return position; } set { position = value; } }
```

to

```
public string name { get; set; }
public string IDnum { get; set; }
public string department { get; set; }
public string position { get; set; }
```

or introduce backing fields:

```
private string _name;
public string name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx for more info on Auto-Implemented Properties in C#.

Please note, that the commonly used naming of public properties is PascalCasing. Your properties in PascalCasing would look like this:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string IdNum { get; set; }
public string Department { get; set; }
public string Position { get; set; }
```