# How to convert class object to LINQ query at runtime?

Tags: c#, query-builder

I have a class named Employee:

```
public enum EmploymentStatus
{ FullTime,PartTime,Unknown };

public class Employee
{
 private long emplNbr;
 private string name;
 private EmploymentStatus st;
 private double wage;

 public long EmployeeNumber
 {
    get { return emplNbr; }
    set { emplNbr = value; }
 }

 public string EmployeeName
 {
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
 }

 public EmploymentStatus Status
 {
    get { return st; }
    set { st = value; }
 }

 public double HourlySalary
 {
    get { return wage; }
    set { wage = value; }
 }
}
```

I want to learn how to generate LINQ query at runtime using this class
by passing the object to whatever function , void , .. any thing
with appointing the query type (insert,update,delete,select)
and retrieving the LINQ query in runtime.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly do you want to achieve? (Note: Your code can be shortened by using [auto-implemented properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6001917/87698).)

Comment: https://i.imgflip.com/ijqk1.jpg

Comment: i want to pass class object to function and return linq query
like the following
public string fun(string querytype, Employee emp)
{
  // auto generate LINQ query using emp object
  return LINQ_query;
}
to invock it 

fun("select",new Employee emp);

Comment: @MohamedMohamed: Can you give an example of what a LINQ query is to you? It doesn't make any sense to "auto generate a linq query"..

Comment: I think he's looking for something like a [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: Your question is far from clear. For one, LINQ is for strict queries; i.e. it doesn't do "insert, update, delete", just "select". For another, what _exactly_ do you expect the output of your hypothetical code to produce? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to edit your question so that it can be answered.