# Different ways to declare properties

Tags: c#, properties

could someone explain to me what is the difference between writing a property like this

```
public string Name{  get; set;  }
```

and this

```
public string Name()
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

if the top one is as easy to write/implement as it seems then why aren't all properties wrote in this fashion?

Comment: Because sometime you need to do something else that store value in getter or setter. Former is basically syntactic sugar for latter.

Comment: or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001917/what-are-automatic-properties-in-c-sharp-and-what-is-their-purpose)