# Difference between two class definitions in c#

Tags: c#, class, properties, field, automatic-properties

Failing finding an answer I can understand, could someone explain the difference between the following:

```cs
// One
private Guid mCategoryID;
public Guid CategoryID
{
    get
    {
        return mCategoryID;
    }
    set
    {
        mCategoryID = value;
    }
}
    
// Two
public Guid CategoryID {get; set;}
```

Is the `get/set` code in the section above: `One` doing the same as `Two` or do they work differently?

Jerry

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/public-fields-versus-automatic-properties

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001917/what-are-automatic-properties-in-c-sharp-and-what-is-their-purpose) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/public-fields-versus-automatic-properties)

Comment: Sweeper's answers provides it quite simply: There is none, it's [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

Comment: As other have already said, its syntactic sugar indeed. But it also avoids the risk of linking the property to the wrong private variable... I would encourage you to use automatic properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Both one and two are same .

- A property which contains a both get and set accessors, then we will call it as read-write property.
- get accessor, then we will call it as a read-only property.
  -set accessor, then we will call it as write-only property.