# Is it possible to assign return value for getter without private backing field C#

Tags: c#, properties, getter

I come across the following example:

```
public class TimeService
{
    public TimeService()
    {
        Time = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
    public string Time { get; }
}
```

We have properties for which, e.g., the following is an example of initializing with empty string:
`public string StringProperty { get; set; } = "";`, but how does the `Time` from TimeService work if getter properties cannot be assigned values directly?

Maybe, I haven't formulate my question properly when browsing, but I haven't found the appropriate answer yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but perhaps you don't know about [automatically implemented properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6001917/5133585)? There *is* a backing field here.

Comment: Your code as shown works. Time will be initialized. What is your actual question?

Comment: @Ralf Auto property is `public string Time { get; set; }`. My qestion is how does `public string Time { get; }` works?

Comment: @Sweeper There is `set` part missing to be autoimplemented

Comment: An auto property without a setter means that its value can only be set in the constructor.

Comment: @SomeBody so it's `readonly`?

Comment: This is a read-only property. It can be initialized via ctor or inline syntax, [compiler generates `readonly` backing field for it](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAULIGYAE4kBUCWBbApgZRwCcA3DAYx1gG9Yk6VlNcCTycAKASlvppnoHpsOJAF4kAEQCGAFxxMcAOgByAewDuitKoAyqgHYBzBXhmEMRrgG4edAL62GKCAAYhuJFSSGcMq0gcYOyA==)