# C# data model, are there any differences between using these form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, datamodel

I'm going to build my MVC Web Application and I created my data models.
I found online many ways to compile a data model code. This is easiest one, using only    public properties:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

But I also found a version using a private variable and a public properies, like this:

```
public class Person
{
    private int id;
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;

    public int Id { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
    public string FirstName { get { return firstName; } set { firstName = value; } }
    public string LastName { get { return lastName; } set { lastName = value; } }
}
```

What is the difference between these two data models?
When is more advisable using the first one or the second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same like asking: what is a difference bwteen *auto properties* and normal properties.

Auto properties:

- easy creation (less to type)
- internal field is generated for you automatically by compiler
- Not possible to debug (set a break point inside the property)

Normal properties

- Sligtly more code to type
- Easy to debug
- More code *can* be injected inside `get` and `set`

Answer (score 2):

If first example compiler will create private field for every automatic property itself, but they behave exactly the same. More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

I would suggest second approach as you have more control how `property` works, but there is nothing wrong in using first one.

Comment: Little bit more info on this subject:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: Important point is that you can later rewrite the first form to the second. Without that affecting any consuming code.

Answer (score 0):

The fiest block you have are auto-properties, and under the hood the c# will be compiled similar to the second block, so in this case there is no difference.  Take a look at these posts here:

[C# 3.0 auto-properties - useful or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304/c-sharp-3-0-auto-properties-useful-or-not)

[What are Automatic Properties in C# and what is their purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001917/what-are-automatic-properties-in-c-sharp-and-what-is-their-purpose)

[Any reason to use auto-implemented properties over manual implemented properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116951/any-reason-to-use-auto-implemented-properties-over-manual-implemented-properties)

If you were implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, then you would need to use the traditional way as you would be interacting with the property in the setter, see example...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx