# why not to use direct property instead use private variable ? May be duplicate but need a specific answer?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

approach 1

```
private string mynameField;
        public string myname
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mynameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.mynameField = value;
            }
        }
```

approach 2

```
 public string mynameField { get; set; }
```

Need a specific difference between these above two?

Comment: No difference, approach 2 is new feature reducing lines of code. This is called `Auto Implemented Property` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: The same in the current state. The above option allows for extra behavoir in the getter and setter

Comment: that backing field needs to be string not bool to compile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# 3.0 auto-properties - useful or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304/c-sharp-3-0-auto-properties-useful-or-not)

Comment: How do you have that much rep on this site and not be able to google simple stuff like this? This is dup'd on this site I don't know how many times and has got to have been covered by 500 blog posts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method with the private field makes it possible to execute some extra code. E.g.:

```
private double _torsion;
public double Torsion
{
    get { return _torsion; }
    set
    {
        if (value.Equals(_torsion)) return;
        _torsion = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could also add some extra logic to the get function. Be careful though, to much logic and side affects are commonly seen as a anti-pattern.

If no extra logic is needed, the auto implemented property has some benefits in code-readability. Under the hood, if no extra logic is added, they will be the same.

(ps: this is an example from a WPF application where the XAML is informed when this property is changed.)