# Why do we need backing fields in C# properties?

Tags: c#, properties, field

**NOTE:** This is **not** a question about auto-implemented properties. Auto-implemented properties are about properties without logic in the getters and setters while I stated in my code very clearly that there is some logic. This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304/c-sharp-3-0-auto-properties-useful-or-not) nither, since the question is really different, and so is the answer.

---

I see a lot of this:

```
private int _age;
public int Age
{
    get
    {
        if(user.IsAuthorized)
        {
            return _age;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        if(value >= 0 && value <= 120)
        {
            _age = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Age","We do not accept immortals, nor unborn humans...");
        }
    }
}
```

But why do we need the backing field? Why no returning the Property itself?

```
public object Age
{
    get
    {
        if(user.IsAuthorized)
        {
            return Age;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        if(value >= 0 && value <= 120)
        {
            Age = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Age","We do not accept immortals, nor unborn humans...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public object Property {get;set;}`

Comment: Your second example is recursive, you'll get a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: Second options leads to `StackOverflow` Exception.

Comment: You don't __need__ a backing field. But the comments in the code suggest that there may be some other logic around the getter and setter.

Comment: @HariPrasad -  i explained why this is not a duplicate... Please reopen the question.

Comment: @Sinatr - How could you say the offered solution is not working if the question doesn't even introduce a problem? There is no solution, just a misunderstanding of a concept. Isn't this site about helping people who have questions about programming? Why being offensive? Is it so hard to be nice? I am here to learn, and there is no such thing as a stupid question.

Comment: @Sipo, my comment was deleted (probably marked as being "rude" or "offensive"), the point is that: you have problem and instead of simply trying what you "thought" you come directly to SO and ask. For me this is a kind of disrespect (laziness). This kind of questions (where the answer is "have you tried it to see it's wrong") is same bad as questions where the answer is "have you tried anything" (where lazy people simply ask for things). I could write an answer where I suggest you to create project in VS and try it, but I think it's enough to simply comment on this matter.

Comment: @Sinatr - I tried it, and I know it doesn't work, I only asked why.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, returning *property itself* leads to *Stack Overflow* exception:

```
public object Property 
{
    get
    {
        return Property;
    }
    set
    {
        Property = value;
    }
}
```

Imagine

```
  MyObject o = new MyObject();

  // cause Stack Overflow exception
  o.Property = null;
```

It easy to see why:

1. setting `Property = null` calls `set`
2. which call `Property = value;` which in turn calls `set`
3. which call `Property = value;`... and so on.

So if property *stores* some value the value should be stored in a *field* (you need a field), we can't use a property to *store itself*. If you want to *shorten* the code, put it like this (auto properties):

```
  public object Property { 
    get; // let .Net create a backing field for you
    set;
  }
```

Comment: @fubo: Thank you for a reasonable question. if property *stores* some value we need a backing field. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @fubo -Dmitry understood my question and answered it very well. This is not a question about auto-implemented properties. Please reopen the question.

Comment: It is also important when calling an external API such as reading / writing to the Windows Registry, or to some database. In some cases, this may be desired, but in other cases, it may be preferable at certain points in the execution of your logic to store the value in a local variable to avoid excessive I/O operations.

Answer (score 5):

The property there is actually just two hidden methods: `get_Property` and `set_Property`. If you return `Property` from the getter of `Property` you are in fact causing an infinite recursive loop which will lead to a stack overflow exception: you are calling the method `get_Property` from the method `get_Property`, which in turn calls `get_Property` and so forth.

EDIT: As clarified in the comments, the property is only the two methods and nothing more. There is nothing to hold data; the backing field is what actually contains the data. If you want to store `Age` as data in the instance, something must hold that data which is why you need the backing field.

Auto-properties automatically create the backing field:

```
public object Property { get; set; }
```

In all other cases, the property is just two methods and all data storage is separate and you must handle it yourself.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about the purpose of the `backing field`.

Comment: @fubo yes, it does. The backing field is the actual data container. Property is just syntactic sugar for getter and setter methods. Property contains no data.

Comment: it could also be used to modidy a result `public string Property { get {return backingfield.Trim(); } }` - in that case auto-properties don't work and you need your `_backingField`

Comment: @fubo: and this contradicts my point how exactly? As I wrote, property is just a pair of methods. OP seems to think that property contains data, which is why he attempted to return `Property` from getter of `Property`.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you set a value to Property, the set-block will be called. So in your example it would be like:

```
Property = 10
-- Inside set: Property = Set
----- Called again set: Property = Set
----------- And so on and so o
```

n

But, you can do the following:

```
    public int Property
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public object Property
{
    get
    {
        return Property;
    }
    set
    {
        Property = value;
    }
}
```

This will return the property itself and end up in a **recursive loop**, a stack overflow. Therefore you want to return another object, for example _property.